# How to track mobx global store changes in componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am playing around with `react` + `mobx` + `mobx-react` library. I have created mobx store to store the app settings(`appSettingsStore`). My react app has 2 components namely`AppHeader` & `AppBody`. The AppHeader has dropdown and onChange value is store in mobx store. In my AppBody component, I call API to get data in `componentDidMount`. The AppBody component is wrapped around the router where different page have different API calls as value changes in `AppHeader` dropdown.

I would like to call API in the AppBody component every time I change the selection in my dropdown. Is there any way I can track the change in my mobx store `appSettingsStore` in `componentDidUpdate`?

I have created codesandbox for reference - https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-flower-vu1js?file=/src/App.tsx

App.tsx

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <AppHeader />
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route to="/" component={AppBody} exact />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

AppSettingsStore.ts (Mobx store for storing global app settings)

```
import { observable, action } from "mobx";

export class AppSettingsStore {
  @observable
  settings = "";

  get getAppSettings() {
    return this.settings;
  }

  @action
  setAppSettings(settings: string) {
    this.settings = settings;
  }
}

export const appSettingsStore = new AppSettingsStore();
```

Header.tsx

```
@observer
export class AppHeader extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        My React App header component
        <select
          onChange={e => appSettingsStore.setAppSettings(e.target.value)}
          style={{ width: 200, float: "right" }}
          value={appSettingsStore.getAppSettings}
        >
          <option value="" />
          <option value="one">One</option>
          <option value="two">Two</option>
          <option value="three">Three</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Body.tsx

```
@observer
export class AppBody extends Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    // API calls
  }

  async componentDidUpdate() {
    // Check if mobx store value is different
    // from previous then call API otherwise ignore
    console.log(appSettingsStore.getAppSettings);
    // API calls
  }

  render() {
    return <div style={{ padding: "5rem" }}>This is App body component</div>;
  }
}
```

I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use reaction for listening settings, like the next
updated ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-borg-dj0oc?file=/src/Body.tsx))

```js
import { reaction, ... } from 'mobx';

@observer
export class AppBody extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.reactions = []; // it needs to dispose reaction on unmount
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    // API calls

    this.reactions = [
      reaction(
        () => appSettingsStore.settings,
        this.handleSettingsUpdates
      )
    ]
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.reactions.forEach((dispose) => dispose());
  }

  handleSettingsUpdates = (newSettings) => {
    console.log('newSettings = ', newSettings);
  }

  render() {
    return <div style={{ padding: "5rem" }}>This is App body component</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi IT's Bruise, thanks for answering my question. Regarding your answer, I have 2 questions. First, is it required to cleanup `reactions` in `componentWillUnmount`? Seconds, can I dispose reaction in `handleSettingsUpdates`? `const (newSettings, reaction) => reaction.dispose()`

Comment: @TEMP Yes, you can call dispose inside handleSettingsUpdates, but as you call dispose(), reaction stops react. If it's fine for you, no problem. But if you need to react on setting changes, before component will unmount, you have to call dispose in componentWillUnmount. It depends on your requirements

Comment: Thanks. Can I do `useEffect(() => {//code }, [appSettingsStore.settings])` in functional component? Is this a good approach or `reaction` is prefered?

Comment: I think both of them will work fine, like componentDidUpdate will work too.
But i recommend to read new documentation of [mobx-react of 6 version](https://mobx-react.js.org/). It's may affect you

Comment: I understood one thing. You don't use inject in your class, that is why componentDidUpdate doesn't work, but reaction works fine. You component just doesn't rerender on any updates

Comment: Yes, I didn't use `inject` because in typescript first arg of inject is typed as `inject(...stores: Array<string>)`. It's like passing a string to a black-box. After reading your answer I prefer would prefer using `reaction` than `inject`.

Comment: @TEMP but without inject i'm not sure that observer will work fine.
i recommend you to migrate to react-mobx version 6 and use hooks instead of inject it may solve your problem with typescript